# Windows terminal server 2012 R2 + Custom credential provider

Tags: c++, windows, windows-server-2012, credential-providers, terminal-server

I have a customer credential provider(CP) which is working fine for Windows client(10) and Windows server (2008, 2012 GUI based only). But when I try to use it for Windows terminal server it's not even loading the Custom CP, no error also. Still, it shows only the default login UI i.e windows default CP. Also I can see my CP is registered in the following HKEY registry HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\Credential Providers{........} and DLL file in System32 directory.

There is no info about Windows terminal server with Custom CP in my MS CP page. I have the following questions to move further,

1. Can we actually implement custom CP for windows terminal servers? is it supported?
2. If yes, what am I missing?  Is there special configuration required to load custom CP in terminal servers?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Are you not seeing your custom provider when doing a remote connection? Or when directly logging in to the workstation itself?

Comment: Actually, both are not working. But the same cp is working with windows server GUI and windows client.

Comment: I am facing similar issue, my CP is working fine in Windows 7 and Windows 10 but I am not able to see it in Windows 2012 R2 server sign in options, Registry keys are registered and also c++ redistributable is installed. Can you tell me if am I missing something? @SaRaVaNaNDM

Comment: @Mohit - I have same problem. My CP work on win8 and 10 but on server r2 2012 do not show. Do you find solution?